# How to use angular services to pass count value to the Component?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-services

I have been trying to develop a coin counter for my application and for the purpose, I created a service for counter and tried to use it in one of my component where the counter function is trigged. But I have been struggling to use the service inside my component. I would really appreciate some help to understand how to use my service inside the component

Below is the code I tried

**coin.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class CoinService {
   public coin =0;

setCount(coinValue:number){
  this.coin+= coinValue; 
}

getCount():number{
  return this.coin;
}

}
```

**one.component.ts**

```
export OneComponent implements OnInit(){

  coin :number = 0;
  constructor(private coinservice: CoinService) {}
  ngOnInit(): void {}

  addTask(){
    this.coinservice.setCount(this.coin);
    console.log('coin:',this.coin);
    this.coinservice.getCount();
  }
  }
```

In the above code for the component , the addTask() is trigged by button click. So on button click, i want to increment the counter, **But the current code logs " coin: 0"** I understand I didnt use the service in the right way inside my component. Can someone show me how to use it in a proper way to get the count value . Thank you in advance!

Comment: `this.coin` is equal to `0` inside `OneComponent`, so your coin service isn't adding anything to the total

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to fully tell what you're aiming to do; however, it looks like you're using the coin service correctly. The issue, though, is that you're not actually adding anything currently (`this.coin` is set to `0` inside the component). Let's try adding a nickel:

```
export OneComponent implements OnInit(){

  coin: number = 5;

  constructor(private coinservice: CoinService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  addTask(){
    this.coinservice.setCount(this.coin); 
    // The total is tracked in the coinservice
    console.log('coin:',this.coinservice.getCount());
  }
}
```